# WSO2 ESB High CPU usage thread blocking http-nio

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am running WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 in a production enviroment.
After a few days it gets wild:

[image]

I did some thread dumps and see that i am getting blocked state on the http-nio-X-Connector-X thread ie: http://pastebin.com/RizJdJDs
Can someone explain what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

These is some JDK bug that can lead to high CPU usages. Please check [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRMINA-678) and also [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/LB-75). Could you please verify JDK version that you are running.

Comment: java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.4.1.el6_5-x86_64 u51-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: Yeah we upgraded to the latest version 4.8.1!

Comment: So you are still experiencing this issue?

Comment: Well, to be honest the deadlock are gone.. but we still have some issues, i will post then in a answer in orderfor analysis.

Answer (score 0):

So we did upgrade the system to the latest 4.8.1 using the hazelcast for clustering.
In order to give some overview please see image:

[image]

In this case we had the 4.7.0 till the 11 where we can notice a drop in both machines and then they started what seemed clustered(resource wize).

After a few days on the 12 we noticed that the CPU was again hitting the ceiling with the new version which we after some debug noticed that statistics was enabled and after a disabling the resources dropped but after that it seemed that the resource consumption was unclustered.

So at this point we are still trying to figure out what can do this...

**UPDATE**
Using 4.8.1 still has CPU usage  issues:
[image]

The JVM Arguments are as follows:
http://pastebin.com/CSimSUPg

and snapshot using visualVM here:
http://speedyshare.com/Nqqar/download/wso2.nps

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue as you, even switched Axis's transportReceiver from the passthrough one to HttpCoreNIOSender, to no avail. On 4.8.1, I still suffer from this issue. The environment is exactly the same as yours (RHEL-like CentOS 6.5), so I'm wondering if this is something specific that isn't triggered on other environments.

Comment: maybe we should sit together and discuss it, probably changing the kernel will solve the issue. I am just across the room... ;)